# I have two char arrays and when their sizes are different the program doesn't read/write them properly

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have a program to do basic things with two char arrays. Everything works fine when the size limit of the first is equal to size limit of the second, but when the size of the first char array is different to the size of the other, the program starts to read/write the strings in a strange way.

For example, if the limit of the first is 31 and the limit of the other is 5, if the typed characters in the first are more than 8 or something like that the program won't let the user typed anything on the second array as if it was full already.

I tried to fix it without using the functions of string.h, but the programs still did the same when the size limit of the two char arrays were different.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LIMIT1 31
#define LIMIT2 5

/*Function: void copy_string(char *pointer_destination, char *pointer_source)
Precondition: it needs a pointer to the direction of memory of the first element of two char vectors and the size limit of the 'destination' vector
Postcondition: it puts all the elements of the 'source' vector into the other until the last element that */

void copy_string(char *pointer_destination, char *pointer_source, int LIMd){

    //Variable declaration
    int i = 0;

    /*Cycle for replacing the element of the 'destination' vector by the element of the 'source' vector.
    When the element of the 'destination' OR of the 'source' is the null character, this cycle ends*/
    for(; i < LIMd && *(pointer_source + i) != '\0'; i++){
        *(pointer_destination + i) = *(pointer_source + i);
    }
    *(pointer_destination + i) = '\0';
}

int main(){

    //Variable declaration
    int restart;
    char username[LIMIT1], string2[LIMIT2];//Here we define the limit for obvious reasons

    //Restart cycle starts here
    do{

        //Data input
        printf("Type your username (maximum 30 characters)\n");
        fgets(username, LIMIT1 - 1, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Type a string of maximum 30 characters\n");
        fgets(string2, LIMIT2 - 1, stdin);
        fflush(stdin);

        printf("Your typed username and your typed second string are, respectively:\n");
        fputs(username, stdout);
        fputs(string2, stdout);

        printf("Concatenating, the username is now\n");
        strcat(username, string2);
        fputs(username, stdout);

        printf("Now I'll copy what is in your username and I'll put it in the second string,\n");
        copy_string(string2, username, LIMIT2 - 1);
        fputs(string2, stdout);

    //Restart cycle switch
    printf("Type '0' to close this program, otherwise it'll restart itself\n");
    scanf("%d", &restart);
    fflush(stdin);

    //Restart cycle ends here
    }while(restart);

    return 0;
}
```

I expected that if the size of the two arrays were different, the program would still read and write them properly (if the size of the first is 3, read from the user only the first three characters and put behing a \0 and if the size of the other is 25 do the same but with 25 as the size limit)

Comment: Can you please provide sample input and output?

Comment: If I remember correct: `string2[LIMIT2]` will allocate for you only `LIMIT2=5` chars, after this place it's not yours. I think you need to use `malloc`

Comment: @A.Akram what difference would using `malloc` make in this code?

Answer (score 0):

You're not very specific about your actual and expected output, but I imagine it's this:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Run the program as posted
2. Get the prompt `Type your username (maximum 30 characters)`
3. Enter `this is an especially long string`

Expected result:

- A prompt that says `Type a string of maximum 30 characters` and lets you enter a new string

Actual result:

- `Type a string of maximum 30 characters` is written to screen but the program continues immediately without letting you enter another string.

This happens because the first `fgets` is set up to read no more than 30 characters from the user. If you enter more, it will only consume the first 30.

The next `fgets` will then consume the remainder of that line instead of a new line, giving the appearance of skipping the prompt.

You should use a large enough buffer to accomodate the line, so that this is not an issue. Alternatively, you can manually read and discard one character at a time until you find a `\n`, effectively draining stdin of the rest of the line.

Comment: _The next fgets will then consume the remainder_ : false, you missed the fflush

Comment: @bruno `fflush` on an input stream is undefined in standard C, and should not be used to clear unread input. On many platforms it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Warning fgets will save the \n if there is enough place to save it, I think your problem comes because in your examples the end of line is saved at least in the usename. So you need to remove it if present.

Warning you give the size minus 1 to fgets, but fgets already read the given length minus 1 to have place to put the null character at the end.

Note the message to read the second string is wrong because it indicates a length 30 rather than 4.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be relying on `fflush(stdin)` to clear any unread input. This is undefined behaviour in standard C, and only works on some platforms as a non-standard extension. I suspect it doesn't work on yours, and either breaks input altogether or does nothing and causes the next `fgets` to read the rest of the input intended for the previous one.

Instead of `fflush`, you can check whether the string read by `fgets` ends in a newline (`'\n'`, which you probably want to remove if it is there). If not, keep reading (and discarding) input until either a newline `'\n'` or EOF is encountered.

(In general I would also recommend not using `scanf` for user input - it's a lot easier to read into a temporary buffer with `fgets` and parse that with `sscanf` as needed.)

Another obvious, but unrelated, problem is `strcat(username, string2);` – this may exceed the length of `username`. You need to leave at least `LIMIT2 - 1` extra space (that you don't allow `fgets` to use), or simply allocate a new array of the correct size after you know the lengths of each.